# How to get path without trailing slash or backslash

Tags: python, path

I want to have a path  like

```
"/path/to/somthing" or in some OS "\path\to\something"
```

as

```
"path/to/something" or "path\to\something"
```

I tried:

```
>>> test = "\ali"
>>> test.strip("/\\")
'\x07li'
```

But it outputs corrupt output.

It may or may not have trailing slashes and it could be a variable passed to a function without knowing its value.

Comment: This seems simple string op, have you tried: `test[1:]` ?

Comment: Just slice off the first character: `test = test[1:]`

Comment: That's because you have corrupt input. You either need `"\\a"` or `r'\a'`

Comment: @Nick it's just the case of `a`? and if I had string variable, the solution was okay?

Comment: @Ahmad yes, it works fine. try `test = r'\ali/'; test.strip(r'\/')`

Comment: @shaktimaan But I'm not sure if it has or not the slash.

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I didn't get, for example if I have a variable like `path` wihtout knowing its value how can I do that?

Comment: `path.strip(r'\/')` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use `os.path` or `pathlib` when working with paths and directories. For example, `os.path.normpath("example/path/")` gives you a standard format for you paths, also without the final slash.

Comment: IMO better answer. normpath takes care of things like "c:\" or simply "\" where you might not want to get rid of the last backslash.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works:

```
path = path.strip(r'\/')
```